# Find the resultant vector after insertions

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an array of elements, along with their insertion position. Find the final array.

Basically, we're supposed to shift the elements by 1 if there's an element already at that index.

```
Example:
arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
index = {0, 1, 2, 1, 2}

Output = {1,4,5,2,3}

Sequence:

1 inserted at index 0 -> {1}
2 inserted at index 1 -> {1,2}
3 inserted at index 2 -> {1,2,3}
4 inserted at index 1, elements shifted -> {1,4,2,3}
5 inserted at index 2, elements shifted -> {1,4,5,2,3}

size of arr = 10^5 (Bruteforce timedout for some tests.)
```

Comment: Rewrite the index[] array to contain absolute positions. -->> `{0 3 4 1 2}`

Comment: @wildplasser Any ideas on how to do that efficiently? All I could come up with was a naive O(n^2) approach.

Comment: Yes, but the naive N^2 appraoach only has to increment values, not shift entire parts of the array to make place.

Comment: what if the index array is {0, 1, 2, 4, 2}? what is the expected output?

Comment: @SomeDude It's guaranteed that the index[i] will be in the range of indices we have at any point in time. i.e., one could rather append it in the end (making a contiguous array), or in the middle.